# How to merge two functions that do same things with different variables

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery

I have these two **Javascript** functions that are equal except for the variables

```
onClickVoteUp: function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var upvoted = this.model.get("upvoted");
    var downvoted = this.model.get("downvoted");
    this.$el.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    if(!upvoted){
        if(downvoted) {
            this.model.set("downvoted", false);
            this.model.upvote();
        }
        this.model.upvote();
        this.model.set("upvoted", true);
        $target.addClass("active");
    } else {
        this.model.set("upvoted", false);
        this.model.downvote();
    }
},
onClickVoteDown: function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var upvoted = this.model.get("upvoted");
    var downvoted = this.model.get("downvoted");
    this.$el.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    if(!downvoted){
        if(upvoted){
            this.model.set("upvoted", false)
            this.model.downvote();
        }
        this.model.downvote();
        this.model.set("downvoted", true);
        $target.addClass("active");
    } else {
        this.model.set("downvoted", false);
        this.model.upvote();
    }
}
```

They are `events` handlers and as you can see they only have different variable, but the algorithms are the same. How would you write only one function to optimize the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write only one function.  You will still need to have a separate function for each event handler, so the best you can do is to have 3 functions whose total amount of code will be less than what you currently have because it will not contain duplicated code. It will not perform faster, but it will be smaller.

So, what you need to do is to extract the common functionality of those two event handlers into a separate, "common" function, and have each event handler call the common function passing it additional parameters telling it how you want it to work.  I am not going to show you code, because this is "Programmers SE", not "Stackoverflow", but I will give you the general direction of thinking:

You need to stop thinking about "upvoting" and "downvoting", and instead start thinking about simply "voting" in a direction which may be either "up" or "down".  This way, the direction can become a variable of your "common" function.

By looking at your code I see that there are a few things that depend on this direction, which you will have to parametrize based on the value of "direction".  One is whether to use the "upvoted" or "downvoted" string literal, and the other is whether to invoke `model.upvote()` or `model.downvote()`.

From what I know it is possible to pass a method reference to a function in javascript, so that your handler can tell the common function which method of `model` to invoke, but it would really help if your model exposed a `vote(direction)` method instead of two separate `upvote()` and `downvote()` methods.

You might even need a fourth little helper function, which returns the opposite direction from the direction that you pass to it, so that if you pass it "up" it returns "down", and if you pass it "down" it returns "up".